# Ajax form won't sent my data

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#msform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#editjeeinde").hide();
    $("#loading").show();

    $('#msform').ajaxForm(function() {
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#done").show();
    });
});
});
```

It just doesn't submit my form to the php page as shown in my html form:

```
<form id="msform" action="sent.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

My submit button and the loading div and finishing div shown after the form has been sent:

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Verzenden" id="submit" />
    </div>
    <div id="loading">
    <p>Bezig met verzenden...<br /><img src="loader.gif" /></p>
    </div>
    <div id="done">
    <p>Uw aanvraag is succesvol ingediend. Wij zullen deze binnen 1-2 weken verwerken en u hiervan op de hoogte brengen.</p>
    </div>
```

It just keeps loading... Anyone see the problem?

Comment: Do you get any error? Does the form submit without Javascript?

Comment: Doesn’t the ajaxForm plugin actually do the same as binding the submit-event? Is `$("#editjeeinde").hide();` executed?

Comment: is there any network traffic captured under browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer myself. You can't use the  `.submit` function together with the `Form` plugin. So I changed it to:

```
$("#msform").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#editjeeinde").hide();
    $("#loading").show();

    $("#msform").ajaxSubmit(function() {
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#done").show();
    });
});
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using jQuery forms plugin. According to [its documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api), this code :

```
$('#msform').ajaxForm(function() {
    // your options
});
```

should be placed in your outside of the `submit` function, just before for instance. Plus, you don't submit the form in your code. You should use this function in you submit function :
    `$(this).ajaxSubmit();`

So in the end, it should looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#msform').ajaxForm({
        // Callback called before the form loading.
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $("#editjeeinde").hide();
            $("#loading").show();
        },
        // Success callback of your form.
        success: function() {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $("#done").show();
        }
    });

    // Change your submit function to load asynchronously your content.
    $('#myFormId').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit();
        return false;
    });
}
```